# Input[type="number"] handler not working properly [Formik, RegExp]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, formik, formik-material-ui

I have an input which can't have more than 2 decimal places. Also I have validation, which doesn't work properly for numbers with lots of zeros.

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLNVg.png)

[Unexpected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7DbX.png)

```
export default function App() {
  const isValidAmount = (amount) => /^$|^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(String(amount));

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik initialValues={{ decimalNumber: "" }}>
        {({ handleChange }) => (
          <Field
            className="input"
            type="number"
            name="decimalNumber"
            placeholder="Decimal Number"
            component={TextField}
            InputProps={{
              onChange: (e) => {
                if (!isValidAmount(e.target.value)) return;
                handleChange(e);
              }
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-almeida-nrorj?from-embed)

Can you please explain: What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML `step` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp) to limit the allowable numbers. In this case you want to limit to hundredths:

```js
<Field
  /* ... */
  step="0.01"
/>
```

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work too.
Thanks for response.